# Cooperation between Eclipse and Crypto++

Tags: c++, eclipse, crypto++

I am trying to use the Crypto++ Library for AES encryption/decryption. Installation went on well, and I created a Project in Eclipse. In the Project Explorer, under the "includes" category, I can see `/usr/include/crypt.h`, `/usr/include/crypt++/aes.h` and `/usr/include/cryptpp/aes.h`.

When I type `#include <aes.h>`, Eclipse interprets it as an "Unresolved Inclusion". On the one hand, it seems normal because `aes.h` is not located directly in the `/usr/include` directory. On the other hand, on every Tutorial I have found they seem to `#include` `aes.h`; neither do they refer to `crypto++/aes.h` nor to `cryptopp/aes.h`.

I have one year's experience in C and C++ using gedit, but this is my first attempt to use Eclipse. I have installed the C/C++ Development Plugin, and the `include` directory settings seem to be correct. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you you've said that's normal since the file are located in a folder inside /usr/include, not directly into the include directory, anyway this has nothing to do with Eclipse or any other IDE but it's just a matter of GCC and the enviromental variable "C_INCLUDE_PATH" if you're using plain C or "CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH" if you're with g++, if you really don't want to use the `#include cryptopp/aes.h` sintax just append the /usr/include/cryptopp folder to the appropriate enviromental variable, maybe with a line like this one in your .bashrc file

```
C_INCLUDE_PATH= $C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/include/cryptopp
```

anyway, I don't really see any problem in using `#include cryptopp/aes.h`

Comment: First of all, thanks for the answer. As about the problem, it lies in the fact that there exist both a `crypto++` and a `cryptopp` directories. Because in the Tutorials they `include` simply `aes.h`, I have no clue which one to use...

Comment: Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: what is your OS? I'm asking because I've just used the crypto library on Arch Linux and Ubuntu and it comes pre-installed with the latest version of OpenSSL into the /usr/include/openssl folder.. You could check wether it exists in your OS..

Comment: I am Using Ubuntu, specifically version 13.04. However, I can't find `openssl` in the `include` directory...

Comment: You're right, Ubuntu has by default only .so files, to install openSSL headers and sources you need "sudo apt-get install libssl-dev".. then the folder /usr/include/openssl appears.. I suggest you to use that one since it is the official supported version for your distro

Comment: Basically, this is the recommended Library by the Tutor; thus I'll go with it. Do you know if there is any difference between the two header sets?

Comment: Oh, whatever... I navigated to the directory using nautilus and discovered that `cryptopp` is actually a link... So they are the same. I wonder why Eclipse shows both! However, is there any way to include `/usr/include/cryptopp` only in Eclipse, without affecting the rest of the system?

Comment: I've never used Eclipse but I don't think so, since in a way or another when you click on your 'build' or 'compile' button Eclipse has to call gcc or g++ which is the one that really evaluates your sources so unless you modify C_INCLUDE_PATH there is no way, but you should be able to do it manually in your makefile adding C_INCLUDE_PATH= $C_INCLUDE_PATH:/usr/include/cryptopp to your compilation step

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll try to figure out the rest! :D